# Count Total from Multiple Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (ticket1, ticket2, ticket3) that contain same field:

```
ticket1:       ticket2:        ticket2:
========       ========        ========
ticket_id      ticket_id       ticket_id
status         status          status
```

And my query just like this:

```
("SELECT (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `ticket1` WHERE `status` =9) AS done,
                        (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `ticket1` WHERE `status` =10) AS Incomplete,
                        (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `ticket1` WHERE `status` =2) AS New")
```

This is to count ticket and filter by status.

[image]

And my question is, how i can count all ticket into total Done, Incomplete, and New from ticket1, ticket2, ticket3.

Help me guys, thanks..

Comment: You have 3 tables, two of which share the same name

Comment: Either way, seriously consider revising your schema, such that you only have 1 table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the 3d table's name is `ticket3`, right?

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket1` WHERE `status` = 9) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket2` WHERE `status` = 9) + 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket3` WHERE `status` = 9) AS TotalDone,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket1` WHERE `status` = 10) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket2` WHERE `status` = 10) + 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket3` WHERE `status` = 10) AS TotalIncomplete,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket1` WHERE `status` = 2) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket2` WHERE `status` = 2) + 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ticket3` WHERE `status` = 2) AS TotalNew
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select status, count(1) from 
(select * from ticket1
union all
select * from ticket2
union all
select * from ticket3) group by status;
```

Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: Oh it took so long, i think this is still face error @Jim Macaulay

Answer (score 0):

you could select from union all

```
select  sum(case when status =  9 then  1 else 0 end)  done,
        sum(case when status =  10 then  1 else 0 end)  Incomplete,
        sum(case when status =  2 then  1 else 0 end)  New,  
        sum(case when status  in (9,10,2)  then  1 else 0 end)  deon_incomplete_new,               
        count(*)   tot  
from (
      select ticket_id, status  from ticket1
      union all  
      select ticket_id, status  from ticket2
      union all  
      select ticket_id, status  from ticket2
 ) t
```

Comment: You have error ?  .. show error message  .. and for performance  .. this should similtar to you 3 select  in subquery ..

Comment: @scaisEdge not entirely. The union most likely creates a temp table in the background and if those tables are big, then it could take significant time. There is no such overhead with the series of subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select sum(case when status = 9 then cnt else 0 end) as done,
       sum(case when status = 10 then cnt else 0 end) as incomplete,
       sum(case when status = 2 then cnt else 0 end) as new
from ((select status, count(*) as cnt from ticket1 group by status
      ) union all
      (select status, count(*) as cnt from ticket2 group by status
      ) union all
      (select status, count(*) as cnt from ticket3 group by status
      ) 
     ) t;
```

Or, you might consider putting the values in separate rows using `group by`.

If performance is an issue and you have lots of other tickets statuses (or more specifically lots of rows with different statuses), then `where status in (2, 9, 10)` in each of the subqueries might help.